# Automatically stretch/fit contents of a paragraph

Tags: horizontal-alignment, paragraphs

I am preparing my thesis and in many places I find the `Overfull/Underfull` warnings. Usually it is not very alarmingly visible in the document but sometimes it is painfully out of the specified margins. The MWE below exhibits one such instance:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{hanging}
    \usepackage{doi}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{hangparas}{.3in}{1}
    Aguero-Valverde, J., \& Jovanis, P. P. (2006). Spatial analysis of fatal and injury crashes in Pennsylvania. \textit{Accident Analysis \& Prevention, 38}(3), 618-625. \doi{10.1016/j.aap.2005.12.006}
    \end{hangparas}

    \end{document}
```

The end product is this:
[image]

As can be seen the text overflows over the margin. How can I fix this? Is there a package or a command that can be used here to make the text "justified".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Somehow the `doi` in unbreakable.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82349/16595)

That's why you have to help LaTeX (which justifies per default) out here. It doesn't but the whole “word” `doi:10.1016/j.aap.2005.12.006` into a new line because it would produce an even worse underful paragraph.

My proposals:

1. Mimic the behaviour of `url` (macro: `\doiurl{…}`)

   ```
   doi:{\urlstyle{same}\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aap.2005.12.006}{\nolinkurl{10.1016/j.aap.2005.12.006}}}
   ```
2. `doi: {\urlstyle…` for comparison (macro: `\doiurl[ ]{…}`)
3. Make use of `\sloppy` (which kind of produce the above mentioned “underfull paragraph”)
4. Insert a manual line-break (`\\`)

   ```
   \\\doi{10.1016/j.aap.2005.12.006}
   ```

Note that the differences between (3) and (4) are not in the last line!

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{url,doi}
\newcommand{\doiurl}[2][]{doi:#1{\urlstyle{same}\href{http://dx.doi.org/#2}{\nolinkurl{#2}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{hangparas}{.3in}{1}
Aguero-Valverde, J., \& Jovanis, P. P. (2006). Spatial analysis of fatal and injury crashes in Pennsylvania. \textit{Accident Analysis \& Prevention, 38}(3), 618-625. \doiurl{10.1016/j.aap.2005.12.006}
\end{hangparas}
\begin{hangparas}{.3in}{1}
Aguero-Valverde, J., \& Jovanis, P. P. (2006). Spatial analysis of fatal and injury crashes in Pennsylvania. \textit{Accident Analysis \& Prevention, 38}(3), 618-625. \doiurl[ ]{10.1016/j.aap.2005.12.006}
\end{hangparas}
\begin{hangparas}{.3in}{1}\sloppy
Aguero-Valverde, J., \& Jovanis, P. P. (2006). Spatial analysis of fatal and injury crashes in Pennsylvania. \textit{Accident Analysis \& Prevention, 38}(3), 618-625. \doi{10.1016/j.aap.2005.12.006}
\end{hangparas}
\begin{hangparas}{.3in}{1}
Aguero-Valverde, J., \& Jovanis, P. P. (2006). Spatial analysis of fatal and injury crashes in Pennsylvania. \textit{Accident Analysis \& Prevention, 38}(3), 618-625.\\\doi{10.1016/j.aap.2005.12.006}
\end{hangparas}

\begin{hangparas}{.3in}{1}
Buck, A. J., Blackstone, E. A., \& Hakim, S. (2009). A multivariate Poisson model of consumer choice in a multi-airport region. \textit{iBusiness, 1}(2). \doiurl{10.4236/ib.2009.12012}
\end{hangparas}
\begin{hangparas}{.3in}{1}
Buck, A. J., Blackstone, E. A., \& Hakim, S. (2009). A multivariate Poisson model of consumer choice in a multi-airport region. \textit{iBusiness, 1}(2). \doiurl[ ]{10.4236/ib.2009.12012}
\end{hangparas}
\begin{hangparas}{.3in}{1} \sloppy
Buck, A. J., Blackstone, E. A., \& Hakim, S. (2009). A multivariate Poisson model of consumer choice in a multi-airport region. \textit{iBusiness, 1}(2). \doi{10.4236/ib.2009.12012}
\end{hangparas}
\begin{hangparas}{.3in}{1}
Buck, A. J., Blackstone, E. A., \& Hakim, S. (2009). A multivariate Poisson model of consumer choice in a multi-airport region. \textit{iBusiness, 1}(2).\\\doi{10.4236/ib.2009.12012}
\end{hangparas}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Or simply use the `uri` package instead of `doi`. `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

Somehow the `doi` is unbreakable. you can adjust the hang dimension.

```
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{doi}

\begin{document}
\begin{hangparas}{.45in}{1}
Aguero-Valverde, J., \& Jovanis, P. P. (2006). Spatial analysis of fatal and injury crashes in Pennsylvania. \textit{Accident Analysis \& Prevention, 38}(3), 618-625. \doi{10.1016/j.aap.2005.12.006}
\end{hangparas}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use `uri` package instead of `doi`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{hyperref,uri}

\begin{document}

\begin{hangparas}{.3in}{1}
Aguero-Valverde, J., \& Jovanis, P. P. (2006). Spatial analysis of fatal and injury crashes in Pennsylvania. \textit{Accident Analysis \& Prevention, 38}(3), 618-625. \doi{10.1016/j.aap.2005.12.006}
\end{hangparas}

\begin{hangparas}{.3in}{1}
 Buck, A. J., Blackstone, E. A., \& Hakim, S. (2009). A multivariate Poisson model of consumer choice in a multi-airport region. \textit{iBusiness, 1}(2). \doi{10.4236/ib.2009.12012}
 \end{hangparas}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A really nice quick fix - but this does not fully address the concerns here. Take for instance another reference:

Buck, A. J., Blackstone, E. A., \& Hakim, S. (2009). A multivariate Poisson model of consumer choice in a multi-airport region. \textit{iBusiness, 1}(2). \doi{10.4236/ib.2009.12012}

Still falls out of margins. Any other ideas?

Comment: @RazorXsr: Use `uri` helps here as in the update.

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine \doi to allow a break before it with \allowbreak. Furthermore, if the break occurs there, fill the remaining (if any) space on the line with blanck space, so that no underfull nor overfull box will happen. Simply add this line

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\doi\expandafter{\expandafter\hfil\expandafter\allowbreak\doi}
```

That is, the MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{doi}

\expandafter\def\expandafter\doi\expandafter{\expandafter\hfil\expandafter\allowbreak\doi}

\begin{document}

\begin{hangparas}{.3in}{1}
    Aguero-Valverde, J., \& Jovanis, P. P. (2006). Spatial analysis of fatal
    and injury crashes in Pennsylvania. \textit{Accident Analysis \& Prevention, 38}(3), 618-625. \doi{10.1016/j.aap.2005.12.006}
\end{hangparas}
\begin{hangparas}{.3in}{1}
Buck, A. J., Blackstone, E. A., \& Hakim, S. (2009). A multivariate Poisson model of consumer choice in a multi-airport region. \textit{iBusiness, 1}(2). \doi{10.4236/ib.2009.12012}
\end{hangparas}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\hfil\break` a simple `\linebreak[3]` is more in the spirit of LaTeX and might also help.

Comment: @Martin: Ok, but I think the one-line redefinition of `\doi` is more efficient because you don't need to edit all entries manually.